# read gmail account without manually enter username and password in android

Tags: android

I am using this code:
[Are there any good short code examples that simply read a new gmail message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303805/are-there-any-good-short-code-examples-that-simply-read-a-new-gmail-message)

but i need to set username and password. If you have sync with gmail you don't need username and password in gmail android application. How can i do the same?

I am searching but i can not find any working solution. I found only this: [android get gmail username and password from account manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639752/android-get-gmail-username-and-password-from-account-manager)

Comment: Why would you be allowed to read email without credentials?

Comment: because you are already connected to google with sync

Comment: being connected to google on my android tablet doesn't mean i want every app to read my emails ...